# What method can I use to develop session control using Django?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-rest-framework

Currently in the company I have developed about six applications with Django, these applications are managed in different databases since they are focused on different departments. They are asking me that access to these applications be done through a single credential, that is, if a user must handle two applications, they should not have two different access credentials, but rather they can access both applications with a single credential.

I have consulted various sources, one person recommended me to develop an application that is only responsible for access, but I am a bit disoriented with this problem.

I appreciate the help!

Comment: Does your company already have some form of centralised user store/service like Active Directory/LDAP? Probably better to get an off the shelf solution rather than developing your own

Comment: At the moment we do not have an Active Directory, currently I manage the deployment of the applications in an ubuntu server dedicated only to that. I was researching and found an LDAP, could I make an implementation of this tool on my server just to solve my problem?